# How to link prebuilt shared/static libraries in ndk build with avoiding the library to get copy in lib/{arch} folder?

Tags: android-ndk

I have two native modules to be build as shared library. Both the modules have dependecy on some other common modules.

I am giving the dependecy in Android.mk file using "PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY", but the problem is the libraries specified with "PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY" will get copied to libs/armeabi folder too.. :(

When I include their respective .jars in the main application it throws an eror saying duplicate copy of libraries..

I have to solve this problem by linking the common libraries in ndk build without using "PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY" so that it will not copy the all dependent libraries to libs/areabi.

Can anybody please tell me how can I resolve this problem ? I have googled about this, but everywhere I see the answer use "PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY" to link with already built shared libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your prebuilt's Android.mk is probably wrong, if you do something like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := mygreatlibrary-prebuilt

MY_LIBRARY_NAME := myGreatLibrary

### export include path
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
### path to library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib$(MY_LIBRARY_NAME).so
### export dependency on the library
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -l$(MY_LIBRARY_NAME)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then the correct library will be copied to the correct place